# How to create generic dynamic types matching input structure?

Tags: typescript, dynamic, types, casting, transformation

I'm building an object schema validation function, and I'm trying to make the return type to dynamically match the structure of the input parameter.

```js
// ----- Types
interface SchemaString {
    type?: 'string',
    required?: boolean,
    default?: string
}

interface SchemaNumber {
    type?: 'number',
    required?: boolean,
    default?: number
}

interface SchemaObject {
    type?: 'object',
    required?: boolean,
    default?: {}
    children?: Schema
}

type Schema = {[key:string]: SchemaString | SchemaNumber | SchemaObject};

// ----- Example

// Stuff happens here
function check<T extends Schema>(schema: T): Magic_Type<T>{
   // Processing
}

const schema: Schema = {
    foo: {
        type: 'string'
    }
    bar: {
        type: 'object',
        children: {
            baz: {type: 'string'}
        }
    }
};

const result = check(schema);

// 'result' type should be:
//
// {
//     foo: string
//     bar: {
//         baz: string
//     }
// }
//
```

The main objective is to have the IDE to perform a proper autocompletion, depending on the structure of the input (and avoid  `{[key:string]: unknown}`):

[image: autocompletion demo]

I've tried the following type transformer, but it does not work as intended:

```js
type Magic_Type<T extends Schema> = {
    [P in keyof T]: typeof T[P]['default']
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things that are preventing you from getting the correct result. First when you do `const schema: Schema = { ... }` you actually loose the type information about literal strings. The solution is to remove `: Schema` annotation (as it looses type information) and use `as const` for the literal, or use a special identity function who's job is to capture literal types.

Next thing is that you have to make `type` property mandatory on your schema otherwise all properties are optional making *any* type match the schema, so you can not do the mapping.

Finally `"default"` property does not have the correct type for objects, so you need to use conditional types instead. Putting it all together you have this:

```js
// ----- Types
interface SchemaString {
    type: 'string',
    required?: boolean,
    default?: string
}

interface SchemaNumber {
    type: 'number',
    required?: boolean,
    default?: number
}

interface SchemaObject {
    type: 'object',
    required?: boolean,
    default?: {}
    children?: Schema
}

type SchemaItem = SchemaString | SchemaNumber | SchemaObject;
type Schema = {[key:string]: SchemaItem };


type SchemaObjectChildrenToType<T extends Schema | undefined> =
    T extends Schema ? SchemaToType<T> : {};

type SchemaItemToType<T extends SchemaItem> =
    T extends SchemaString ? string :
    T extends SchemaNumber ? number :
    T extends SchemaObject ? SchemaObjectChildrenToType<T["children"]> :
    never

type SchemaToType<T extends Schema> =
    { [P in keyof T]: SchemaItemToType<T[P]> };


// Stuff happens here
function check<T extends Schema>(schema: T): SchemaToType<T>{
   // Processing
    return null as any;
}

function makeSchema<T extends Schema>(schema: T): T {
    return schema;
}

const schema = {
    foo: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    bar: {
        type: 'object',
        children: {
            baz: { type: 'string' }
        }
    }
} as const;

// const schemaAlternative = makeSchema({
//     foo: {
//         type: 'string'
//     },
//     bar: {
//         type: 'object',
//         children: {
//             baz: { type: 'string' }
//         }
//     }
// });

const result = check(schema);

result.bar.baz.endsWith("bar"); // works!

// 'result' type should be:
//
// {
//     foo: string
//     bar: {
//         baz: string
//     }
// }
//
```